# Can't run detox in release mode Android

Tags: android, react-native, detox

Steps to Reproduce

detox build --configuration android.emu.release
detox test -c android.emu.release

my detox config:

```
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "android.emu.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/isracard/debug/app-isracard-debug.apk",
        "build":
        "cd android && ./gradlew assembleIsracardDebug assembleIsracardDebugAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Nexus_6_API_25"
    },
    "android.emu.release": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/isracard/release/app-isracard-release.apk",
        "build":
        "cd android && ./gradlew assembleIsracardRelease assembleIsracardReleaseAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Nexus_6_API_25"
    }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "e2e/config.json"
  }
```

Detox, Node, Device, Xcode and macOS Versions

Detox: 9.0.5
React Native: 0.57.3
Node: v10.4.1
Device: Nexus_6_API_25

Device and verbose Detox logs

Failed: [Error: Error: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with tag value: is "modalButton" and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE)

Comment: did u find any solution??